# Get column header and row header on cell click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I already have the function working on selecting a cell, using this:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    //do things here
}
```

I want it get the text from the header of the column (this is within thead and then it's own th tag), and also get the row header, this is the left most column on the table and is also denoted under a th tag.

HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Day/Time</th>
    <th>10:00</th>
    <th>11:00</th>
    <th>12:00</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <td>Cell data</td>
    <td>Cell data</td>
    <td>Cell data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <td>Cell data</td>
    <td>Cell data</td>
    <td>Cell data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <td>Cell data</td>
    <td>Cell data</td>
    <td>Cell data</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please include some attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help!

Comment: Providing actual HTML instead of describing it would be much better...

Comment: I haven't actually attempted any solution. I looked at a few on SO, however none seem entirely relevant and simple enough. It's not exactly a fancy table. Expected results is just the text from the column's header.

Comment: @Fabricio I've added some sample HTML.

Comment: @TheBritishBloke it seems to have made all the difference. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here we go, exotic blend of jQuery and pure JS:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {  
    var time = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex],
        day  = this.parentNode.cells[0];

    alert([$(day).text(), $(time).text()]);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fv3gZ/

I would recommend to delegate click events to the table, instead of binding click on each `td`, it would increase performance.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I wasn't aware that you it would work if you delegated it to the table, I thought it would have just taken it as though you clicked the entire table, rather than a single cell. Thank you so much!

Comment: @dfsq `.click( handler(eventObject) )` is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`. Do you know if there is a shortcut for `.on( "click", 'td', handler )`?

Comment: @Fabricio No, there is no shorter version.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for the confirmation. After I asked I was reading the _fine_ manual for .on(...) and  for .click(...) and got to the same conclusion...

Comment: what if i have a table structure like <td class="show">Cell data</td> and i wan t to display this header data by clicking on only those cells who's having show class.

Comment: Try `$('table').on('click', 'td.show', function(e) {`

Answer (score 1):

As your html structure if you wanted to get header of corresponding cell you can use `siblings`
Try this:

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/29/

```
  $('td').on('click',function() {
       var text = $( this ).siblings('th').text();
        alert(text);
    });
```

Comment: @TheBritishBloke: did you want this?

Comment: That's almost perfect, how do I go about also selecting the time headers? I presumed it would be .parent however it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
titles = document.getElementsByTagName("th")
for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
  td[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert(titles[this.cellIndex].innerHTML);
  }, false);
}
```